VS Code Intellisense loading forever in typescript project
Problem
It keeps being stuck in Loading when I hover on a variable/method/import.
Normally you can ctrl + click to see the reference on the entity.
Background info

Using VS Code version 1.95.2 for a typescript project
Other ts projects don't have the issue
This project is fairly large, but other people don't have this problem on VS Code
It had been working fine a few days ago for me, only me making very minor code changes
Manually updated VS Code from 1.8x to 1.95.2 a few days ago

Attempts tried:

Restart VS Code alone --> does not work
Reboot PC --> works temporarily (stops working after an hour or so)
Switch Intellisense typescript version from vs code version to workspace version --> works temporarily after restarting VS Code alone
Switch Intellisense typescript version to use the nightly ts version as seen in this git issue --> works temporarily after restarting VS Code alone
Clean reinstall of the same version 1.95.2 --> does not work
Should be unrelated: npm install again after deleting node_modules and package-lock.json --> does not work

Thinking of now experimenting with clean installing to the older version I had. Or migrating to use other IDEs.
Edit: I find that if I disable the github copilot extension, Intellisense works fine again.

Having the same issue from yesterday

@AlexanderNenashev refer to point #3 of the "Attempts Tried", tried that already

Same issue here, copilot was the reason. I tried everything including,

Delete all vscode extensions
Reinstall only needed extensions

Still the same.
However, when i disabled copilot extension it started working again.

I had a similar issue today. The only way to make it work is to disable GitHub Copilot and create a new chat dialog instead of leaving the old conversation there. I guess the issue is caused by GitHub copilot's trying to mess around the workspace
